# Binding function in a module to an onclick event

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, onclick

I have an html file with the following script:

```
<script type="module" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

This is where I put my app logic with other imports. Inside this `app.js` file, I have a function called `test()`;

```
function test() {
    console.log("aaa");
}
```

This function is called in an `onclick` event in an HTML span element appended dynamically using this code:

```
buildSideBar(technologies) {
    if(technologies.length > 0) {
        let spans = ``;
        const loader = document.getElementById('loader');
        const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
        for(const technology of technologies) {
            spans += `<span onclick="test()">${technology}</span>`;
        }
        loader.style.height = '0';
        loader.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        sidebar.innerHTML += spans;
        sidebar.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
}
```

The spans are added as intended, however, when I press them I get an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
>       at HTMLSpanElement.onclick ((index):1)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `test` is likely not a global, so the HTML element doesn't have visibility to it.

Comment: Why are you generating HTML that has an inline onclick at all? [Just attach the event listener to the element via JS.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Comment: @VLAZ Attaching the event listener dynamically requires me to actually create DOM elements which is a lot of work for me right now, I'm trying to be as minimal as possible.

Comment: `technologies.map(technology => {var el = document.createElement("span"); el.textContent = technology; el.addEventListener(test); return el; }`

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks, as of my main answer, I've found the solution.

Answer (score 3):

The `test()` function wasn't visible outside of the module, the solution was to add it to the `window` object so it can be accessible.

```
window.test= test;
```

And as @VLAZ mentioned, there is also the solution to dynamically bind the spans to an onclick.